# How can I allow file uploads (pdf) to a specific category on each item of a list?

Tags: file-upload, pdf, file

I am looking to have all users be able to upload PDF docs to a specific spot on our SharePoint list. We have many columns, one for "dispositions" and when a disposition is filled out and ready to upload, I want any user to be able to upload it to a specific line (in which the disposition corresponds to) easily and effectively so others can view the upload at any time on the same line. To me, this seems like a very easy thing to do but I am waiting for full user access and am unfamiliar with SharePoint.

Answer (score 0):

You can attach files to a custom list item --if it's not a document library. That should suffice for your needs. Otherwise there is no way to upload to a column, it would have to be uploaded then referenced through a lookup column --which you could do some pretty cool ways to link all supporting files of a case (if that's the kind of disposition you are referring to).

Another idea is to use document sets. All the files of a document set can stay together and all files in the document set will have tagged metadata associated with it.